# Element {overflow: auto} with visible scrollbars despite proper sizing of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I have a scrollbar problem when having css overflow set to auto.

### Description

PARENT **A** (overflow:auto) has 2 CHILDREN columns with a good sizing (overflow to default is needed so menus that are too big continue to be visible and do not cause another scrollbar to appear (except on the parent)).
So if one of the children **B** have a bigger child **C**, it will cause overflow on the parent **A**.

### Problem

If child **C** is removed, parent **A** scrollbars are NOT removed by the browser even if it should be the case.

Child **C** can be created by any javascript plugin, so I do not control when it is actually there (added or removed) in **B**.

### Only fix found (but it's more a hack than anything else...)

Setting **A** overflow to hidden then back to auto ***after*** removing **C** works.
(I'm testing that on Chrome)

There's a jsfiddle link to show every step (including the little "hack"):

http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/h5m2g/2/

```
var $children = $('.containerChild').text('');
// 1. Placing children with the correct sizing
$children.each(function(i, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.css({left: i*200});
});

// 2. Simulate something added by a plugin (example: adding an absolute menu)
$elementThatDoesReflow = $('<div></div>').css({width:400, height:10,'backgroundColor':'green'});
$children.eq(1).append($elementThatDoesReflow);

// 3. Simulating the end of that plugin (example: removing an absolute menu)
$elementThatDoesReflow.remove();

// BUG HERE: Scrollbars WILL appear even if every sizing is correct now since the element that caused the reflow has been removed

// 4. The only fix I found: since every thing has the correct size, just ask the browser to check again its overflow by disabling overflow and re-enabling it just after that
$children.parent().css({overflow:'hidden'});
setTimeout(function(){
   $children.parent().css({overflow:'auto'});
}, 10);
```

### Is there a way to not have to run this scrollbar fix?

Because I have no control over plugins, I'd like to know if anyone has found a solution for this problem that do not require a overflowRefresh() method that would disable (hidden) and enable (auto) the overflow.

Comment: here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/h5m2g/16/ (overflow:visible)

Comment: Container needs to be overflow:auto

Comment: If the problem is the menu, will be also visible http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/6eEN9/12/ or if you want menu scrollable, you can set the overflow auto to menu instead of container http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/3MfdZ/3/

Comment: Sorry to say this but I already know that solution and it's not the real problem.
The real question is: how to remove scrollbars after it has appeared without the trick I mentionned in my post?
As I said I do not want to edit the menu inside B (or any other thing within it) that cause scrollbars on the parent (A). Because having scrollbars on A is normal when its contents overflows. What is not good is that A keep the scrollbars after the children of B have been removed.
FYI A and B overflows are meant (that is: auto for A and visible for B).

Comment: By now the only solution come up to me is to use a combination of selector :not and :empty (if not empty) for the child div. Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/KQ9F2/19/  in the fiddle child div have overflow:auto, for hte second if not empty set overflow:hidden (or visible)

Comment: I explained earlier that I absolutely needed to keep overflow:auto on the container (A) AND keep overflow:visible on containerChildren (B). But you've changed B to overflow:auto... I can't do that in my case because I need things to be visible.

Comment: in that fiddle if you change the overflow of containerChildren to visible or remove it, nothing change. It was only to show you difference between first and second child behavior. Try to remove the comment at style of .second:not(:empty) in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/KQ9F2/30/ If there's nothing can help you i think you need to use js.

Comment: :empty in your example works because width(.container>.first>menu) <= width(.container).
Simply add a few pixels to the .menu width and you'll see that it does not work. Plus the fact that it suppose that children B of the container have to be empty in order to work, which almost never the case in realistic scenarios (B elements can have many elements).

Comment: You are right. To do that works i've applied :not(:empty) to both containerChild. Cause I need to check both overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/KQ9F2/47/ As you said is not realist having empty contents for the childs div. By now i don't have any other idea in css. Hope someone come up with something good.

Comment: you can wrap your menu width a div? http://jsfiddle.net/jybFK/19/

Comment: You're just trying to avoid the rule I set. I do not want the overflow to be hidden or auto for B (I want to have them overflow:visible) and neither its undetermined children (which I do not control).